# plots on multiple instances of graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm using the d3 library to plot a bar graph with JSON objects recieved from the server through websockets. What is happening though is that each time the graph is plotted it draws a new instance of a graph. So I end up with multiple graphs.

But I want the JSON data to be all plotted onto the same one graph.

Here's my code:

```
      ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888/dh");

      var useData = []
      //var chart;

      var chart = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg:svg")
         .attr("class", "chart")
         .attr("width", 420)
         .attr("height", 200);


      ws.onmessage = function(evt)
      {  
        var distances = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        data  = distances.miles;
        console.log(data);

        if(useData.length <= 10){
          useData.push(data)
        }
        else
        {

           var draw = function(data){        
           // Set the width relative to max data value
           var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(useData)])
            .range([0, 420]);

           var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(useData)
            .rangeBands([0, 120]);

           var rect = chart.selectAll("rect")
            .data(useData)

            // enter rect
            rect.enter().append("svg:rect")
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("width", x)
                .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

            // update rect            
            rect
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("width", x)
                .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

           var text = chart.selectAll("text")
                .data(useData)

           // enter text
           text.enter().append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", x)
                .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2; })
                .attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
                .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
                .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
                .text(String);

            // update text
            text
                .data(useData)
                .attr("x", x)
                .text(String);
        }
    useData.length = 0;
       }          
    }
```

How can I plot all points onto on graph which is being constantly updated?

It's a shame that d3 cannot handle data in real-time and update charts accordingly, or if it can that there's no clear tutorial/ explanation of how to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you're creating a chart every time with:

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("class", "chart")
.attr("width", 420)
.attr("height", 20 * useData.length);
```

Rather you need to check if chart exists, and if so, don't call that line.

```
// outside of .onmessage
var chart;

// inside of .onmessage
if (!chart) {
    chart = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", 420)
    .attr("height", 20 * useData.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, now it plots a graph once only, but does't update that graph with new data.

Comment: Perhaps because height would only be set once. Might need to do `chart.attr('height', 20 * useData.length)` outside of the if statement

Comment: Putting chart.attr('height', 20 * useData.length) outside the if statement prints no graph now.

Answer (score 0):

Like Brian said you keep creating a new `svg` element at every onmessage event. However, in D3 you don't need to use an `if` statement to check for element existence; after you do a data join, the `enter()` selection will only contain the elements that did not exist yet:

```
// data join
var chart = d3.select("body").selectAll(".chart")
    .data([useData]); // if you wanted multiple charts: .data([useData1, useDate2, useData3])

// enter
chart.enter().append("svg") // this will only execute if the .chart did not exist yet
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", 420);

// update (both new and existing charts)
chart
    .attr("height", function(d) { return 20 * d.length; });
```

The concepts of the data join, enter(), update(), and exit() selections are explained in the [Thing with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) article. See also the 3 [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/3808218) articles.

You have to use a similar approach when you update or add new rect elements in your chart. Assuming for the moment that useData contains all accumulated data (although the useData.length = 0 might mean that is not the case):

```
// data join
var rects = chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; }); // use the data bound to each chart

// enter
rects.enter().append("rect");

// update
rects
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.yValue); }) // not sure what your data structure looks like
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.xValue); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

// exit
rects.exit().remove();
```

Some suggestions how to update a path with real time data are given in [Path Transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/).

Comment: Thanks for that....When I run it I get a  "ReferenceError: y is not defined" in the console log. As you said you don't know what my data structure looks like. It is simple, useData is just an array of numbers eg: [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]. How would I get rid off that Reference Error?

Comment: The y function is your ordinal scale... Do you have a jsfiddle or something that you can share? The chart part, without the websocket stuff.

Comment: See http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html how to create proper transitions etc. Maybe that example is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. The tutorial isn't what I want, as I want to be building on top of each bar as data comes in.